# Error in connecting App Engine backend to Async Task

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am trying to write a backend service in Android, which reads a remote database and executes a query on it, returning the result in a ResultSet object. This is the code for my Java Bean which I return from the API call (called SQLResult):

```
package com.gradai.rushhour.backend;

import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class SQLResult
{
    ResultSet result;

    public SQLResult()
    {

    }

    public ResultSet getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(ResultSet rs)
    {
        result = rs;
    }
}
```

Now I try to use this API (called sqlBackend) in an AsyncTask in the actual app. In the onPostExecute function, I am getting an error:

```
error: incompatible types: com.gradai.rushhour.backend.sqlBackend.model.ResultSet cannot be converted to java.sql.ResultSet
```

This is the code for the said function:

```
protected void onPostExecute(SQLResult result)
{
    ResultSet rs = result.getResult();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, rs.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

I don't get why is a ResultSet class being created in the backend model. Please help me in understanding what is going on. I'll be glad to provide further code if needed for debugging.

EDIT: These are the import statements used in the AsyncTask program:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;  
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.gradai.rushhour.backend.sqlBackend.SqlBackend;
import com.gradai.rushhour.backend.sqlBackend.model.SQLResult;

import java.io.IOException;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

Also, please note that: I tried to convert the ResultSet in the API function to an ArrayList, and changed the SQLResult class to contain the same. Now, when I try to access the ArrayList in the same function, I get the error that a List is expected instead of an ArrayList. Could that be helpful?

Comment: Check your import package. It has hazard. It can't know "you use your ResultSet or java ResultSet"

Comment: I have added the import statements for the AsyncTask in my post. Do you see any problem now?

Comment: Also, I haven't defined any ResultSet class on my own. Why am I getting this error then?